# App Crashed when posting the local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation

Well, we are playing videos in our App. The scenario is that we are using the notifications to pause the other videos which are currently playing.

Now the problem is that after some time, the app crashes while posting the notification to pause the other videos, saying that unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Here is the exact error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton pauseVideoNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x167d3100'
```

Comment: can you please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if you have any customized action -pauseVideoNotification: configured to your button via interface builder. The cause of the crash is that a select has been sent to a object (in this case an UIButton instance) which doesn't implement this selector. It could also be the case of issue in memory management, i.e, a target of the action (-pauseVideoNotification:) has been deallocated and the same memory location 0x167d3100 is assigned to another object (which doesn't respond to -pauseVideoNotification:). You should first inspect your code, if you can't find the root of the problem, enable NSZombie object detection in the debug scheme and reproduce the crash, then debug it with the console log again.

Comment: Your approach is right.
But the problem was something else.
We have resolved the problem as of now.

Comment: Cool to hear that. Could you share your finding then?

Comment: Could sound strange to you but in the line just before that, we were using a method which was available only in ios8 and later. So we tried replacing that with appropriate code and it worked after that.